# How to get access properties of object returned in AJAX response?

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I am trying to get List of all customers using AJAX from my Spring MVC controller. Controller response is sending back List accurately. But now I don't know that how can I get element of List and their properties from AJAX Response. 
Here is Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ShowAllCustomers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Object AllCustomersList() {
    List<Customer> customers= customerService.getAllCustomers();
    return customers;
}
```

and Here is Client side:

```
function AjaxGetCustomers() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'customers/ShowAllCustomers',//this is url mapping for controller
        success : function(response) {
            alert(response.get(0).first_name);
                         //this response is list of object coming from server
        },
        error : function() {
            alert("opps error occured");
        }
    });
}
```

but this is not working. How to access each Customer object and its properties?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can send the `List` as JSON string from the Controller.

Comment: can you please give me simple example please

Comment: You can surf net and find out , search for sending JSON from MVC Spring Controller and how to read that in jquery.

Comment: OK thanks. One thing will I need to add any dependency or not?

Comment: Yes some JSON library like Jackson or GSON.